# Type of inputRef - TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component that accepts as props an `inputRef`

**My Interface**

```
interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  body: text
  inputRef?: any // I am not sure which TypeScript type I should use
}
```

**My component**

```
const MyComponent = ({
  classes,
  body,
  inputRef
}: Props) => {
  <TextField
    body={body}
    inputRef={inputRef}
  />
}
```

I am not sure which TypeScript type should I use for `inputRef`. I currently declare it as `any` but I want the right type.

I tried to use `React.createRef<TextInput>()` but I get the error: `Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'createRef'`

I have as types version: `"@types/react": "^16.9.21"`

Comment: I think you want `React.ElementRef<T>`

Comment: I tried that but I get "Cannot find name T"

Comment: You need to specify a type. `T` is a parameter. E.g. `React.ElementRef<TextInput>`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I figure that out. When I create a reference to an element:

```
const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

I hover over the variable `wrapperRef` in VSCode to see what type it is. In this case I see:

```
const wrapperRef: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
```

So, what you want to pass is `RefObject<HTMLDivElement>`.

Now if you do want an `ElementRef`, go ahead and use that (I'm not sure what kind of ref you are trying to pass). When you look at documentation or the actual type file you will see `<T>`. This is a Typescript Generic. It allows you to pass a type to the type declaration. Here is some [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) on it with many examples.